# jQuery - start script if browser width is more than 960 px

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, screen-size

I was using this script so that certain DIVs would appear when scrolled by, but when using a mobile device it doesn't work so well. For instance, when using an iPad, the DIVs whould never show up if I didn't lift my finger from the screen or until the page stopped scrolling.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.hidden').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() / 4;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Now I just want this script to start if the browser window is larger than 960, in order for it not to work on mobile devices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function to get the browser's width, and only execute the code if it exceeds 960:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 960) {
            $('.hidden').each( function(i){
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() / 4;
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the function within a check of the windows width `if($(window).width() >= 960)`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ($(window).width() >= 960) {
        $(window).scroll( function(){
            $('.hidden').each( function(i){
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() / 4;
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
                }
            });
        } 
    });
});
```